# Не обновляется запись в /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux, сеть, dns, altlinux

Дистрибутив ***Alt Linuix (version 8.2)***.

Есть **2** сетевых интерфейса с работающими конфигами `/etc/net/ifaces/*interface*/[ipv4address|ipv4route]` (доступ к ним есть, все хорошо).
В каждой из этих директорий также лежат файлы `resolv.conf` для настройки ***DNS***, и они оба идентичные. Значения из этих файлов по итогу должны подхватываться и передаваться в файл `/etc/resolv.conf`, но к сожалению, значение ***nameserver*** в этом файле остается неизменным ***127.0.0.1***, Хотя ***search*** (полное имя домена) подхватывается успешно. ***reboot*** и ***restart network.service*** не помогают.

Содержимое `/etc/net/ifaces/*interface*/resolv.conf`:

- search xxx.xxx.xxx
- nameserver x.x.x.x

Answer (score 2):

У Вас dnsmasq или systemd-resolved установлен как локальный ресолвер. В этом случае nameserver отправляется в `/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` или `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, а dnsmasq или systemd-resolved проксирует и кеширует запросы с 127.0.0.1.

Он может включаться настройками openresolv и NetworkManager или подхватываться etcnet напрямую.

[https://www.altlinux.org/Ресолвер](https://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)